# Remove documents older than a year from a subcollection in Google Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google's Firestore, and I'm trying to remove all the documents older than a year in a subcollection. Here is the current structure:

```
data:
  domain1.com:
    entries:
      1:
        created_at: 1507052341
      2:
        created_at: 1607052341
  domain2.com:
    entries:
      1:
        created_at: 1607052341
  domain3.com:
    entries:
      1:
        created_at: 1607052341
      2:
        created_at: 1507052341
      3:
        created_at: 1507052341
```

This is what I've done so far **trying** to find the entries older than a year, but it is not working as expected and the snapshot is always returning as empty:

```
let a_year_ago = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 31536000

this.db.collection("data/*/entries")
      .where('created_at', '<', a_year_ago)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          return false
        }

        return snapshot
      })
```

Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions on how I could retrieve these entries older than a year and get them removed?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. First, I had to create a new index with the field I wanted to search for, and then update the code to search the information through this index.

1. Open Firestore.
2. Go to Indexes > Single Field > Add exemption.
3. Fill in the exemption details:

- **Collection ID:** `entries`
- **Field path:** `created_at`
- **Collection Group:** enabled

4. Update your code to use the collection group:

```
let a_year_ago = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 31536000

this.db.collectionGroup('entries')
      .where('created_at', '<', a_year_ago)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          return false
        }

        return snapshot
      })
```

Boom!